# We are Using SVN for version control System, how to ignore certain middle revisions and accept other revisions using svn?

Tags: svn

We are Using SVN for version control System, if we start with a repository revision of "1" and person A, B, C, D and E commit code changes (revision 6 is latest revision after E commits).  Suppose programmer C's changes must be backed out but we want to keep changes from person A, B, D, E.  How do we do this?

Hope it explains to some extent.

Million Thanks in Advance
MB Chand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need *reverse merge*.

If you use TortoiseSVN client, it's easy (http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html):

> If you want to merge changes back out of your working copy, to revert
>   a change which has already been committed, select the revisions to
>   revert and make sure the Reverse merge box is checked.

If you use command line, it is a bit more complicated (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html):

> An extremely common use for svn merge is to roll back a change that
>   has already been committed. Suppose you're working away happily on a
>   working copy of /calc/trunk, and you discover that the change made way
>   back in revision 303, which changed integer.c, is completely wrong. It
>   never should have been committed. You can use svn merge to “undo” the
>   change in your working copy, and then commit the local modification to
>   the repository. All you need to do is to specify a reverse difference.
>   (You can do this by specifying --revision 303:302, or by an equivalent
>   --change -303.)

```
$ svn merge -c -303 ^/calc/trunk
--- Reverse-merging r303 into 'integer.c':
U    integer.c
--- Recording mergeinfo for reverse merge of r303 into 'integer.c':
 U   A-branch

$ svn status
 M      .
M       integer.c

$ svn diff
…
# verify that the change is removed
…

$ svn commit -m "Undoing change committed in r303."
Sending        integer.c
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 350.
```

> When we talk about “removing” a change, we're really talking about
>   removing it from the HEAD revision. The original change still exists
>   in the repository's history.

Comment: Thank you, It serves my purpose

Comment: @user2450573: In that case, please mark this answer as the correct one, will help other users to find it as relevant.